# Segmentation fault while using getchar

Tags: c, printf, getchar

I am writing following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    //      printf("enter some argument \n");
    int count_words = 0;
    int count_char = 0;
    int cnonalpha = 0;
    char s;
    printf("enter string");
    while( ((s = getchar()) != EOF) && (s != '\n') )
    {
        if( (s >= 'a' && s <= 'z') || (s >= 'A' && s <= 'Z') )
        {
            count_char++;
            //putchar(s);
        }
        else {
            putchar(s);
            cnonalpha++;
        }
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "%s: error writing stdout\n", s);
}
```

This is giving me a segmentation fault. What could be the reason for this?

**Update 1**
As per answers below I have changed the program
actually what I am trying to do is take input from stdin by getchar and then in a while loop print character by character the input taken on stdout or store it in a variable and compare the character values using isalpha
here is another program that I wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ()
{
  int c;
  int n=0;
  puts ("Enter text. Press Enter to exit sending input");
  while ((c=getchar())!='EOF'){
          if (isalpha(c))
          else{
         putchar (c);
          n++;
          }

  }
  return 0;
}
```

~
What I want to do is print non alpha charachters that might be entered and count their number.

Comment: `getchar()` returns `int`, not `char`.  `char s;` is an incorrect type.  And `(s>='a'&&s<='z')||(s>='A'&&s<='Z')` is also wrong in assuming an ASCII character set - letters are not guaranteed to be represented consecutively.  Use `islower()` or `isupper()`.

Comment: Your %s needs to be a %c

Comment: actually what I am trying to do is take input from stdin by getchar and then in a while loop print character by character the input taken on stdout or store it in a variable and compare the character values using isalpha, getchar returns int is there any other function that I can use to do get character and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

The segmantation fault because you pass the pointer to the printf but your variable is char. The integer value of the char in impicity converted to the pointer (and of course the place it is pointing is unpredictable) and when the printf tries to dereference it invokes the Undefined Behavior - and anything can happen, segfault, pizza order ....